# Java: list files recursively in subdirectories with Apache commons-IO 2.4

Tags: java, recursion, subdirectory, apache-commons-io

I'm trying to list files with the extension ".xls" in the root directory and its sub-directories, using the following code with `Apache Commons-IO 2.4` library. I am checking the size of the `collection<File>`, but it gives 0. I don't see where could be wrong in the code. Could you please help me with this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File rootDir = new File(args[0]);

    Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(rootDir, new RegexFileFilter("[a-zA-Z].xls"), DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY);

    System.out.println("collection size:" + files.size());

}
```

Comment: Your regular expression does only match one character before the extension?

Comment: oh, good call. I should have used [a-zA-Z]*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this works:

```
    final String[] SUFFIX = {"xls"};  // use the suffix to filter

    File rootDir = new File(args[0]);

    Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(rootDir, SUFFIX, true);
```