# Getting a list of all JSP pages in the catalog?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I  have a service which must verify if a given page exists in WEB-INF/pages/info/ catalog. But I don't know how to implement this task. Are there any suggestions how to implement it?

UPD:

My rough implementation

```
    @Service
    public class ValidateUserAccessToPageService {
    public boolean validate(String page, HttpServletRequest req) {
        if (!req.getRequestURI().equals("/favicon.ico")) {

            ServletContext ctx = req.getServletContext();
            Set<String> pages = ctx.getResourcePaths("/WEB-INF/pages/info/");

            for (String p : pages) {
                if (getLogicName(p).equals(page)){
                    System.out.println("Found matching!");
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    String getLogicName(String page) {
        return page.substring(page.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, page.lastIndexOf(".jsp"));
    }
    }
```

And controller logic

```
    @Controller
    public class RedirectController {

    @Autowired
    ValidateUserAccessToPageService service;

    @RequestMapping ("/{page}")
    String redirect (@PathVariable String page, HttpServletRequest req) {
        return service.validate(page, req) ? page : "error";
    }
    }
```

Comment: does it need to go recursively into subdirectories?

Comment: maybe you could give apache commons fileio a try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776063/java-list-files-recursively-in-subdirectories-with-apache-commons-io-2-4

Comment: `ServletContext#getResourcePaths()` ... http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourcePaths%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Ok. Seems all right. I write simple solution. Is it OK?

Comment: Looking at the question again `getResource()` is probably better for your use-case. It should return NULL if the file does not exist. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: BUT BE CAREFUL that this might lead to potential security issues. If you allow user to specify any file, he might be able to get for example application configuration out of `/WEB-INF/classes/myconfig.properties`. If you really want to implement something like this, I would validate the `page` parameter to be just alphanumeric and hyphen for example (i.e. he would provide you only with `/WEB-INF/pages/{pageParam}.jsp`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ServletContext#getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method to check resource (e.g. JSP file) existence. This method will return `null` for resources which does not exist.

But **be careful** - your implementation as is might introduce some security problems. If you allow user to specify any file, he might be able to get for example application configuration out of `/WEB-INF/classes/myconfig.properties`. If you really want to implement something like this, I would validate the `page` parameter to be just alphanumeric and hyphen for example (i.e. user would provide you only with `/WEB-INF/pages/`**`{pageParam}`**`.jsp`).